# How to check if a function (e.g. server-running-p) is available under Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to check if `server-running-p` is available in my .emacs file before calling it. I already have the following:

```
(if (not (server-running-p))
    (server-start))
```

But on some computers where I use Emacs, calling `(server-running-p)` gives an error because said call is not available. So I want to check if `server-running-p` is available before calling it. I thought `boundp` would do the try, but calling `(boundp 'server-running-p)` return `nil` even though the `(server-running-p)` call succeeds. What's the right way to check that calling `server-running-p` won't fail... or at least to suppress the error if said call fails. (And what kind of weird object is `server-running-p` anyway that `boundp` returns `nil`, but calling it succeeds?)

This is on Emacs 23.2.1, if it makes any difference.

---

Actually found the answer. You have to use `fboundp` for this instead of `boundp`, for some reason.

Comment: The reason is that you can have a function and a variable with the same name (e.g. `font-lock-mode`).  Hence you need different functions to ask "Is this a variable?" and "Is this a function?"

Comment: Thanks. I had completely forgotten about that particularity of some Lisp languages. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`boundp` checks to see if a *variable* is bound. Since `server-running-p` is a *function* you'll want to use `fboundp`. Like so:

```
(if (and (fboundp 'server-running-p) 
         (not (server-running-p)))
   (server-start))
```

Answer (score 17):

A simpler way is to use "require" to make sure the server code is loaded.  Here's what I use:

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
    (server-start))
```

Comment: I am also trying to keep my .emacs compatible with both Emacs and XEmacs. In that case, using `fbounpd` seems safer to me, no?

Comment: @ChristianHudon, this is not just about compatibility.  This version and the other one do two different things.  This one loads the `server` package if it wasn't already loaded.  The other version only starts the server if the `server` package was already loaded elsewhere.  So I think this version is more self-contained.  I don't know about XEmacs, but a more compatible alternative might be to use `(load "server")` instead (instead of `(require 'server)`, that is).

Answer (score 4):

ryuslash’s suggestion was really helpful, but I modified it for my .emacs:

```
(unless (and (fboundp 'server-running-p)
             (server-running-p))
  (server-start))
```

This gets the server running even if server.el hasn't been loaded—`server-running-p` is only defined when server.el is loaded, and `server-start` is autoloaded.